# change logo while scrolling based on section class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need some help with my jquery script ,
i need to change logo img while scrolling  in my wordpress site (im using elementor) so if section with class =" dark logo " the dark logo appear else the white logo , i tried it a script it work for some sections and i can"t figure out the reason of the problem
im stuck here , can anyone help me plz , im newbie in js world

```js
var whitelogo = "https://svgshare.com/i/UZP.svg";
var blacklogo = "https://svgshare.com/i/U_S.svg";
var initial = "https://svgshare.com/i/UYs.svg";
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
  let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('section').each(function ()
    {
    
      
  if ($(".dark").isInViewport()) {
    console.log("dark");

    $(".logo ").attr("src", blacklogo);
  } 
    else  {
    console.log("light");

    $(".logo ").attr("src", whitelogo);
  }
})
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  margin : 35px;
 
}

#section1 {
  background: #0b46eb;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#section2 {
  background: #ffc703;
   width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
#section3 {
  background: #1f262b;
   width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >
  
  <img class="logo" src="https://svgshare.com/i/UYs.svg"  > 
   
  </div>






<!-- logo weelo  -->
<section  id="section1"  class="light"></section>

<!-- change logo color to:  wee black -->
<section class="dark" id="section2"></section>
<!-- change logo color to:  wee white  -->
<section class="light" id="section3"></section>
<section class="dark" id="section2"></section>
<section  id="section1" class="light"></section>
```

Comment: Lucky for you, there is a dedicated API for that in JavaScript called `intersection observer`. Read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: thank you @JerryBen its a great API , the problem is i couldn"t adapt it with my needs with a tight deadline  , i was hoping to fix my code ..